# How to share a customised SharePoint form by PowerApps to all SharePoint Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form, powerapp

I have a multiple lists which are similar, in other words they have the same fields,

In order to customise a SP List form, I use PowerApps (for example to manage field visibility for a certain users). I succeded to do that quickly and easily.

My question now, since the lists are similar and they must have the same customised form, I am wondering if there is anyway to **Share the previous customised form** with the other lists forms without repeating each time the customisation :/ .

PS: If I go to PowerApps and look for a way to save the application as a template or something like that, the button is disabled like it shown bellow:

[image: Screenshot from PowerApps]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Save as" function is disabled by default because SharePoint forms cannot be saved as new apps and used as template.

This feature is currently not available. See the UserVoice post below:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/Save-powerapps-form-for-Sharepoint-list-as-a-template/idi-p/93694

What we can do is create an app from a SharePoint list instead of custom forms. The app will be saved under Apps and can be exported, shared or used by SharePoint multiple lists.

[image]

Here are your references:

[Create a canvas app in Power Apps from a SharePoint list.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/app-from-sharepoint)

[Export solutions.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/export-solutions)

[Embed a canvas app on a model-driven form.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/model-driven-apps/embed-canvas-app-in-form)

Comment: and what about the data sources that this app will use, for example the first created app use the data source of List A, when I share it with List B it will automatically use the data source of List B ?

Comment: No, the app would be "tied" to a single data connection, aka, a single sp list. You could create an app for each list, but then you'd have to repeat each customization for each app.

Comment: @AIMENBOULAHIA When you exported the package, it can be shared and used as a template. Every time you use it for another list, it becomes a new app. You’ll have to manually set the connection and change the data source for each app.  As Mike2500 said, one app one connection.

Comment: Alright, that will be a little bit weird for the SharePoint adminstrator